# Finding a matrix whose eigenvalues are just the real parts of the eigenvalues of a known matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a square real matrix $\textbf{A}$. Generally the eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ can be complex, i.e. $\lambda_k=a_k+b_k\sqrt{-1}$.

I want to find a matrix whose eigenvalues are $a_k$. Please note that I do not want to calculate the eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: seek for a **companion matrix** for such a modified polynomial

Comment: @janmarqz  Thanks. But I don't have the values of $a_k$ as I don't want to solve the characteristic polynomial of matrix $\textbf{A}$. So, I cannot find the companion matrix of the modified characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Again, If you knew the eigenvalues $\lambda_k=a_k+ib_k$ hence the characteristic polynomial is $$(x-\lambda_1)^{n_1}(x-\lambda_2)^{n_2}\cdots(x-\lambda_r)^{n_r},$$ for some positive integers $n_1,...,n_r$, next you construct the polynomial $$(x-a_1)^{n_1}(x-a_2)^{n_2}\cdots(x-a_r)^{n_r},$$ and give a companion matrix.

Comment: If you have any matrix $A$ it is easy to calculate eigenvalues with WolframAlpha, for example

Comment: @janmarqz   You are right. I am aware that eigenvalues can be computed  by Wolfram and a bunch of software packages. Actually, I am looking for a theorem that let me generate a new matrix which has real eigenvalues and they are identical to the real parts of the eigenvalues of the original  matrix. Something like the definition of similar matrices, but excluding the imaginary parts.